# Need help to create/correct a powershell script for account termination

Tags: powershell

I am trying to complete a powershell script to automate account termination. I wanted to first capture some user information and write it to a csv before I then disable the account and remove all groups. I can easily run the script in individual parts, but when I create a loop it only works on one account in my text file. I am not to familiar with using objects but was told that I should learn and utilize them.

I have already tried to run the code without the desired results. The below code only has the capture part as I need to figure out how to include the rest as well.

```
$user_name = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\AD Test Files\*.txt'
foreach ($user in $user_name){
    $users = Get-ADUser $user -Properties samaccountname,givenname,surname
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $users | Select -Expand Name
    $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        samaccountname = $users.samaccountname;
        givenname = $users.givenname;
        surname = $users.surname;
        memberOf = ($groups | Out-String).Trim()
    }
}
$data | Export-Csv C:\Users\username\Desktop\Term.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're overriding `$data` each iteration of the loop, which could explain why it's only outputting one account. Instead, you could make it an array and add to it in each iteration (notice the `+=` in the loop):

```
...
$data = @()
foreach ($user in $user_name){
    ...
    $data += [PSCustomObject]@{
        ...
    }
}
$data | Export-Csv ...
```

Comment: you may want to mention that `+=` on an array is SLOW for "large" collections. a faster method would be to use `$Data = foreach () {}` so that PoSh puts the entire collection into `$Data` all at once. [*grin*]

Comment: Nice, did not know that! Thanks @Lee_Dailey

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] the speed up from avoiding `+=` can be more than an order of magnitude with large numbers of items OR with items that use lots of RAM.

Comment: Thank you both. I have since modified the code but my logic is failing me. The data that is written to csv is only one cell.  
        $Data = foreach ($user in $user_name)
            {
                $users = Get-ADUser $user -Properties samaccountname,givenname,surname
                $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $users | Select -Expand Name
                $cusobj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    }
}
$Data | Export-Csv'

Comment: If you do it Lee_Dailey's way, take out the `$cusobj = ` above. This will make each iteration of the loop "insert" into the array that the foreach returns.

Comment: Absolutely phenomenal. Thank you very much. Ok so now if I want to add my Disable and Remove would I add that in a new loop after the data capture?

Comment: Yes that would be a way of doing it. `$data` will still have all the records you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple solution if you want to get back data from a foreach.:

```
$all = foreach{}
$all | Export-Csv C:\Users\username\Desktop\Term.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```